# Append dict to list of dict

Tags: python

I'm getting members from a Google group using the directory API. This is what is returned:

```
{'etag': '"..."',
 'kind': 'admin#directory#members',
 'members': [{'email': 'a@a.com',
              'etag': '"..."',
              'id': '....',
              'kind': 'admin#directory#member',
              'role': 'MEMBER',
              'type': 'USER'},
             {'email': 'b@a.com',
              'etag': '"..."',
              'id': '...',
              'kind': 'admin#directory#member',
              'role': 'MEMBER',
              'type': 'USER'},
              ...],
'nextPageToken': '...'}
```

There are multiple pages being returned and I want to append the next set of members to the `members` key of this dictionary...I think.

Here is my code so far:

```
for group in groups_list:
    members_service = service.members()
    member_request = members_service.list(groupKey=group['email'], maxResults=200, roles='MEMBER')     
    memberEmails = {}
    while member_request is not None:
        member_results = member_request.execute()
        memberEmails.update(member_results)
        member_request = members_service.list_next(member_request, member_results)
```

I don't think `memberEmails.update(member_results)` will work here because it overwrites and updates existing keys.

How can I accomplish this? or what are some alternatives?

Comment: what do you mean by 'append'? You can't append to a dictionary

Comment: @walker It's a list

Comment: then can't you just use `list.append({'...', ...})`?

Comment: How does `memberEmails` correspond with the dict you're showing? Please make a [mre] with your desired output and the example input -- like show us each `member_results` (anonymized, ofc).

Comment: I've never used this API, but couldn't you simply get all members at once? I don't know why that wouldn't be possible. But maybe you want to operate on them in chunks?

Comment: If I check the type of ```member_results``` it returns dict so I thought I was working with a dict with a key (members) that contains a list of dicts. The Google Directory API, from what I understand, returns a maximum of 200 results per page. Should I declare ```memberEmails``` as  list instead of a dict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if you want to treat memberEmails like a list and extend it with the value associated with the `members` key in the result. For example:

```
for group in groups_list:
    members_service = service.members()
    member_request = members_service.list(groupKey=group['email'], maxResults=200, roles='MEMBER')     
    member_emails = list()
    while member_request is not None:
        member_results = member_request.execute()
        member_emails.extend(member_request['members'])
        member_request = members_service.list_next(member_request, member_results)
```